# i have latest create-react-app installed. how can i get the app.js that used to come with create-react-app@1.5.2

Tags: reactjs, npm

I have no knowledge of react and npm . In order to to learn react i am tried to follow this tutorial
[a  youtube link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ke90Tje7VS0)!

i was instructed to run `npm i -g create-react-app@1.5.2`
but i accidentally ran `npm i -g create-react-app`

now the files (e.g app.js) that are created are different from the tutorial

With my limited understanding i believe what has happened is that the latest version of create-react-app has got installed in my windows 10 system, and simply running `npm i -g create-react-app@1.5.2` now, is not
helping me to downgrade to desired version.

=====Edit

No soluition still -

what i tried

a) - `npm uninstall -g create-react-app` 
followed by `npm i -g create-react-app@1.5.2`

b) `rm -rf $DIR replace $DIR with the name of the directory created by create-react-app then rerun create-react-app`

The app.js is still different from the one generated i the tutorial.

To illustrate what is the difference between two app.js files, ----

**app.js using 1.5.2 - tutorial screenshot]**

[image: app.js using 1.5.2]

**app.js that is getting created on my system.**

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <p>
          Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
```

Edit 2 =======

I found a solution. 
I have posted the answer.

Comment: That should work for downgrading. Unless you mean you expect downgrading create-react-app to change the files in your project to the previous version?

Comment: Delete the files that your original `create-react-app` command made and run it again. Downgrading your global CRA module isn't gonna change any existing files in your project

Comment: yes, how to change the files, since I can't follow the tutorial otherwise.

Comment: `rm -rf $DIR` replace $DIR with the name of the directory created by create-react-app then rerun create-react-app

Comment: @SoZettaSho does't work - see my edits

Comment: So it's not just CRA that's the problem unfortunately. The easiest way you can fix this is see if the tutorial you are using posted their source somewhere e.g. on github, then you should clone the project along with the `package.json` and then npm install. 
If it doesn't provide source code it's a bad tutorial and you should find another one (there are plenty of react tutorials out there).

Answer (score 3):

I am answering my onw question.

I am able to get the app.js i wanted to create matching the tutorial by using this command

```
create-react-app my-react-proj01 --scripts-version=react-scripts@1.1.4
```

I saw that the react-scripts version in package.json of youtube tutorial was 1.1.4

I found the solution by reading this link [hello-create-react-app-2](https://www.telerik.com/blogs/hello-create-react-app-2)

Comment: You are a god. Thank you MAN . Really helped me

Answer (score 0):

Try running

```
npm uninstall -g create-react-app
```

first and then installing desired version

Comment: What do you get if you type create-react-app --version

Comment: it is showing 1.5.2. however this is what it shows when i create an app 
Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts...


+ react-dom@16.8.6
+ react@16.8.6
+ react-scripts@3.0.1
added 1402 packages from 727 contributors and audited 888986 packages in 309.619s
found 0 vulnerabilities

Comment: I have 1.5.2 installed on my machine as well and just tried create-react-app and can confirm I am getting the same App.js file as you are.  I don't know why there is a discrepency between the two.

Comment: I found the solution.